# How do I extract transformed axes from a PCA on spectral data to carry out further analysis and determine important wavelengths using R?

Tags: r, pca, spectral-analysis

I am using R to work with a large set of spectral data from 48 different samples (a combination of different types of waste fines and soils) and trying to determine if these can be differentiated by spectral characteristics. I've trimmed, smoothed, binned, visually analysed,identified peaks, plotted, and carried out a PCA to explore/reduce my data. I've included plots for a few of my samples below:
[image: AD stands for air dry, FC is field capacity, and SAT is saturated - the moisture levels I investigated for each different sample. Waste samples are the top two, soil samples are the bottom two.]
This is where I get stuck. I think I'm interpreting the results of my PCA correctly - following is a small sample:

```
wavelength  PC1          PC2         
440  0.21346388 -0.203888840  
465  0.23812642 -0.165769920  
490  0.25535560 -0.115942621  
515  0.26409500 -0.042751356 
540  0.25571588  0.072759577 
565  0.21329858  0.240141788 
590  0.14779569  0.354308668 
615  0.11800394  0.406438803 
640  0.05287909  0.459469282  
665 -0.06526022  0.430522967  
690 -0.17874835  0.292308921  
715 -0.22794663  0.179020759  
740 -0.25105080  0.109572330  
765 -0.26113417  0.059239926  
790 -0.26531615  0.007708572  
815 -0.26462611 -0.031793585 
840 -0.26069395 -0.061597354 
865 -0.25497653 -0.083364774 
890 -0.24827131 -0.097537491 
915 -0.24270352 -0.105792034
```

According to my PCA results, PC1 explains 71% of the variation in spectra and PC2 explains 22%. I've decided to select values greater than 0.25 (or less than -0.25) as indications of relative importance, so 490-540nm and 740-890 for PC1 and 590-690 for PC2. I've also plotted the loadings as follows:
[image: PC1 and PC2 loadings vs wavelength]

The problem is that I don't know how to proceed from here. Peers have suggested I extract transformed axes from my PCA to see which wavelengths are important, and other suggest I carry out further analysis on the PCA results. I've tried researching both of these and keep coming up blank, hence my question. Can any of you brilliant minds advise me as to how to extract transformed axes using R or what other kinds of analyses I could carry out from here? Many, many thanks in advance.